# Python : How can I add something to a list recursively?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I've read so many answers regarding this question, but none of them solved my problem :(

I have write a recursive function for showing the Fibonacci numbers as below:

```
def fib(arg) :
    if arg <= 0 :
        print("Please choose a number greater than 0.")
    elif arg == 1 :
        return 0
    elif arg == 2 :   
        return 1
    else :
        return fib(arg-1) + fib(arg-2)
```

Now I want the results to be added into a list. **Numbers must add into a list recursively.**
for example I entered an 8 as arg and I want a list with these numbers to be returned: [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
By adding recursively, I mean something like the one I did above in else part.
I've tried many different things but none was the answer!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you write a function that returns a list of Fibonacci numbers up to a given number. Then to get the next Fibonacci number, you only need to add up the last two numbers of the list. You can get them from indexes `-1` and `-2`.

```
def fiblist(n):
    if n<=0:
       raise ValueError("Number should be greater than zero.")
    if n==1:
       return [0]
    if n==2:
       return [0,1]
    fibs = fiblist(n-1)
    next_value = fibs[-1] + fibs[-2]
    return fibs + [next_value]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first 2 index you can save the values and later for all the values you can get the value as `fib_list[current_index] = fib_list[current_index-1] + fib_list[current_index-2]`

The full code:

```
def fib(arg, fib_list):
    if arg <= 0:
        fib_list.append(0)
    elif arg == 1:
        fib_list.append(1)
    else:
        fib_list.append(fib_list[-2] + fib_list[-1])
    return fib_list

n = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))

fib_list = []
for i in range(n):
    fib(i, fib_list)

print(fib_list)
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked very well. But in the question that I was writing my code according to that, it wants us to enter a function as the input after running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
def fib(arg):
    if arg <= 0:
        print("Please choose a number greater than 0.")
    elif arg == 1:
        return [0]
    elif arg == 2:
        return [0, 1]
    l = fib(arg - 1)
    l.append(l[-2] + l[-1])
    return l
```

Comment: It was great, Thanks. just for "if arg<=0" part I faced RecursionError that I fixed it with the help of one of the other answers in this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small change to your function to return array instead of returning a number and on every recursive call, you call append to previous list. Something like this would work fine,

```
def fib(arg) :
    if arg <= 0 :
        raise ValueError("Please choose a number greater than 0.")
    elif arg == 1 :
        return [0]
    elif arg == 2 :   
        return [0, 1]
        
    previous = fib(arg - 1)
    *_, secondlast, last  = previous 
    return previous + [secondlast + last]
```

> print(fib(8)) gives result as you expect [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of single point of exit, when possible, so I designed my solution accordingly.  I realized that Python has the perfect function `range()` to consolidate cases `1` and `2`.  Finally, I tried to maintain your API:

```
import sys

def fib(arg):
    sequence = []

    if arg <= 0:
        print("Please choose a number greater than 0.", file=sys.stderr)
    elif 1 <= arg <= 2:
        sequence += range(arg)
    else:
        sequence += fib(arg - 1)
        sequence.append(sum(sequence[-2:]))

    return sequence

print(fib(13))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]
>
```